# Google Dart: Dart strrev() function

Tags: dart

I'd like to know if there's any Dart function like PHP's **strrev()**. If not, could you please show my any source code how to make it on my own?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found one in the API, as a brand new Dart user (as of this afternoon). However, reversing a string is pretty easy to do in any language. Here's the typical O(n) solution in Dart form:

```dart
String reverse(String s) {
  var chars = s.splitChars();
  var len   = s.length - 1;
  var i     = 0;

  while (i < len) {
    var tmp = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[len];
    chars[len] = tmp;
    i++;
    len--;
  }

  return Strings.concatAll(chars);
}

void main() {
  var s = "dog";
  print(s);
  print(reverse(s));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lists can be reversed, so you can use this to reverse a String as well:

```
new String.fromCharCodes("input".charCodes.reversed.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

May be a standardized reverse() method will be implemented in future in List (dart issue 2804), the following is about 8 to 10 times faster than the previous typical solution:

```dart
String reverse(String s) {
  // null or empty
  if (s == null|| s.length == 0)
    return s;
  List<int> charCodes = new List<int>();
  for (int i = s.length-1; i>= 0; i-- )
    charCodes.addLast(s.charCodeAt(i)) ;
  return new String.fromCharCodes(charCodes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this instead of others.

```
String try(str) {
  return str.split('').reversed.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String theString  = "reverse the string";

List<String> reslt = theString.split("");
List<String> reversedString = List.from(reslt.reversed);  
String  joinString = reversedString.join("");
print(joinString);
```

Ouput: gnirts eht esrever