# Compare a string left to right, right to left in Dart

Tags: split, compare, dart

I am attempting to check to see if a string is a palindrome.

Example:

radar = radar = TRUE

iwant = tnawi = FALSE

Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to check if a word is a palindrome. There are two ways to do this. You can check the word for equality against itself reversed, or you can check the characters against the position they are supposed to match up against.

Dart's String doesn't have a reverse() method yet, so the second approach is probably the easiest for now:

```
bool isPanlindrome(String word) {
  for (int i = 0; i < word.length ~/ 2; i++) {
    if (word[i] != word[word.length - i - 1]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This works, but be careful, calling [] on string returns a single character string, probably more efficient way would be using word.charCodeAt(i) etc.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the dart functions as

```
bool isPanlindrome(String input){
  return input == input.split('').reversed.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As David said (but not in Dart ?), you could write:

```
bool isPanlindrome(String s) {
  return s == reverse(s);
}
String reverse(String s) {
  // null or empty
  if (s == null|| s.length == 0)
    return s;
  List<int> charCodes = new List<int>();
  for (int i = s.length-1; i>= 0; i-- )
    charCodes.addLast(s.charCodeAt(i)) ;
  return new String.fromCharCodes(charCodes);
}
```

see recent post about [reverse()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982759/google-dart-dart-strrev-function/13002807#13002807)

Comment: String reverse(String s) {
  var chars = s.splitChars();
  var len   = s.length - 1;
  var i     = 0;

  while (i < len) {
    var tmp = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[len];
    chars[len] = tmp;
    i++;
    len--;
  }

  return Strings.concatAll(chars);
}

void main() {
  var s = "dog";
  print(s);
  print(reverse(s));
}

Comment: @Peter I prefer my version ;-) . see in the second answer in the same  post.

Answer (score 0):

```
String reverse(String s) {
  var chars = s.splitChars();
  var len   = s.length - 1;
  var i     = 0;

  while (i < len) {
    var tmp = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[len];
    chars[len] = tmp;
    i++;
    len--;
  }

  return Strings.concatAll(chars);
}

void main() {
  var s = "dog";
  print(s);
  print(reverse(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    bool ispl= true;
    String x = "This is the place you will enter the input";
    int j = x.length -1; 
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length / 2; i++) {
      if (x[i] != x[j]) {
        ispl = false;
        break;
      }
      j--;
    }
     print(ispl);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple answer which is this:

```
bool isPalindrome(String x) {
    if (x.startsWith(x) == x.endsWith(x)) {
      return true;
    } 
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
class Solution {
  bool? isPalindrome(int x) {
    String num = x.toString();
    String reversedNum = num.split('').reversed.join('');
    
    if(num == reversedNum){
      return true;
    } else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

It’s better with `nullsafety`.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has  a few answers. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?